# Linking a SQL Server 2008 (Mixed Mode) to a SQL Server 2000 (Windows Authentication)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, sql-server-2000

I am trying to link a production database (SQL Server 2000) that is on Windows authentication to a test database (SQL Server 2008) that is on mixed mode authentication.

I have already tried the code below from [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic699311-149-1.aspx#bm699348):

```
DECLARE @LinkName     SYSNAME   SET @LinkName    = 'PRODUCTIONSERVER'
DECLARE @SrvName      SYSNAME   SET @SrvName     = 'PRODUCTIONSERVER'
DECLARE @LocalLogin   SYSNAME   SET @LocalLogin  = 'sa' --login on test db
DECLARE @RmtLogin     SYSNAME   SET @RmtLogin    = 'DOMAIN\UserName' --win auth login on prod db
DECLARE @RmtPwd       SYSNAME   SET @RmtPwd      = 'password' --win auth password for the login on prod db

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Master..Sysservers WHERE IsRemote = 1 AND SrvName = @LinkName)
BEGIN
   EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server = @LinkName, 
                          @srvproduct = '', 
                          @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', 
                          @datasrc = @SrvName

   EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = @LinkName, 
                          @useself = 'false', 
                          @locallogin = @LocalLogin, 
                          @rmtuser = @RmtLogin, 
                          @rmtpassword = @RmtPwd
END
```

...a linked server is successfully added but when I try a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTIONSERVER.ProdDatabase.dbo.ProdTable
```

I get an error:

```
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 0
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\UserName'.
```

I have also tried logging into the prod database using the mentioned windows authentication credentials (my personal login) and I can get through.

The reason for the linking is because I want to test the merging of live data (from sql 2000) into the test database (sql 2008).

Any ideas on how I can link the servers?

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to have a workaround (thanks to a colleague's help) by an SSIS package that:

- Imports the data from production to test server into a temp table that was created in the SQL2008 database
- Executes the MERGE script (in a SQL task), which performs the merges from the temp table into the real table to be updated